# infowindow.setContent method display only last Account Name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am doing `alert` in `for` loop, the variable `acName` is showing correct result but its not working in `infowinow.setContent`.

Code:

```
function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                var acName = name[i];
                infowindow.setContent(acName);

                alert(acName);
            }  
            infowindow.open(map, marker);   
        });
    }
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need is to make sure that the acName is not just a var object, but rather a string (since you can only input a string or string of html code into the setContent method).

Your line should be:

```
infowindow.setContent(acName.toString());
```